# .closest() in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

I am able to hide a DOM tree which look in this way by using `.closest()`.

```
<div class='parent'>
  <!-- some html code -->
  <div class='child'>
  </div>
  <!-- some html code -->
<div>

$('.child').closest('parent').hide();
```

It will be possible to get the same effect just by using CSS?
If yes, how?

Comment: no, there's no an *ancestor* selector in CSS like `.child < .parent`. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I would like to hide something which looks like `.child < .parent`

Comment: You need to remove that space between `$('.child').` and `closest('parent').hide();` by the way.

Comment: There is cssParentSelector polyfill available, if you want to make it "work": https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector

Comment: @zvona: I wonder how many times that script has to be updated with all those changes to the spec. The syntax it currently claims to be "CSS4" is incorrect and has never been correct.

Answer (score 4):

No selector currently exists that can select a previous or parent element.

There is a level 4 selector that is [currently being developed](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject).

So in the future, you may be able to do something like this:

```
!.parent > .child { display: none; }
```

But until then, you'll have to stick with

```
$('.child').parent();
```

in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

No. [See for yourself](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), no such selector exists in CSS3, and not in [CSS2 either](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Answer (score -8):

Might be able to use this

```
.child:parent .parent{display:none;}
```

http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: *"Let's be clear here, just in case someone is finding this from a search engine: there are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3"* (cit.) - those are only suggested implementation, not actual implementation

Comment: It's incredible just how many people have misconstrued that article as suggesting that such a selector does exist.

Comment: aaaand that's why we have jQuery.